# Explicit template instantiation with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have several template classes `Impl` (with some abstract methods) that are partially implemented in CPP files so that I need to explicitly instantiate my templates for the linker to find it, like this:

```
template class Impl<T0>;
template class Impl<T1>;
template class Impl<T2>;
...
template class Impl<Tx>;
```

As the number of types `Tx` grows, I would like to find a better way than to manually expand these lists of explicit instantiations in all necessary files. I thought I could use variadic templates for this, so I tried the following:

```
template <template <class> class, class...>
struct type_map;

template <template <class> class BaseT, class... Ts>
struct type_map<BaseT, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<BaseT<Ts>...>;
};

typedef std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> MyTypes;
```

And in the CPP file:

```
template class type_map<Impl, MyTypes>;
```

However, this didn't instantiate the templates as I intended (the linker complained about the missing symbols).

Is there a way to make this approach work (i.e. instantiate the template without instantiating an object of it) or a totally different approach that could solve my problem in this situation?

Comment: do you try to create dll's? maybe you have to add the export macro to your `type_map` type

Comment: @Angew I have several classes that work like that, which is the reason for my problem. I tried to formulate my question a little bit clearer.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch No, I don't use DLLs. This is only related to the problem that the compiler does not generate template instances that are needed on other compile units.

Comment: One possible solution is to use macro. Try to use [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) or [`BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/list_for_each.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with variadic templates, but you can do it with the preprocessor.

I see two options. One would be to use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
// Definitions:
#define ARGUMENTS (T0)(T1)(T2)(T3)(Tx)

#define INSTANTIATE(maUnused, maTemplate, maType) \
  template class maTemplate<maType>;


// Usage:
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(INSTANTIATE, Impl, ARGUMENTS)

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(INSTANTIATE, Impl2, ARGUMENTS)
```

Another option would be to use the [X macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) trick:

**x.hpp**

```
X(T0)
X(T1)
X(T2)
X(T3)
X(Tx)

#undef X
```

**using_file.cpp**

```
#define X(maType) template class Impl<maType>;
#include "x.hpp"

#define X(maType) template class Impl2<maType>;
#include "x.hpp"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there is no other approach in this case. I only got the variadic template method to work if my classes are not abstract. Thanks anyway!